# Call Ionic function from the state views options

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a controller 'ProjectController' which has various CRUD functions inside.

I want to be able to call my API when loading a view and without having to create another controller.

Pseudo code:

```
.state('app.my-project', {
    url: '/projects/my-projects',
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/my_projects.html',
            function: myProject()
        }
    }
});
```

And in my controller:

```
.controller('ProjectCtrl', function($scope, $state, $auth, $http, $ionicPopup, $rootScope) {

    $scope.myProjects = function() {
        // foo
    }

});
```

So the goal is that when setting up the states, I can call a function instead of just going to a controller?

The example im using is that when setting up the state for "my projects" I can call a function from within the controller.

Instead of having to create individual controllers for each action.

Comment: Is this the whole question...?

Comment: @spb just added some more info :)

Comment: @Lovelock, onEnter() callback isn't suitable for you needs? (see https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#onenter-and-onexit-callbacks)

Comment: @beaver Interesting, ill have a look at it :)